# Spark Worker node stops automatically

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am running Spark Standalone cluster and on submitting the application, the spark driver stops with the following error.

```
16/01/12 23:26:14 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20160112232613-0012/0
16/01/12 23:26:14 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20160112232613-0012/0 interrupted
16/01/12 23:26:14 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
16/01/12 23:26:14 ERROR FileAppender: Error writing stream to file /spark/spark-1.4.1/work/app-20160112232613-0012/0/stderr
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:283)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender.appendStreamToFile(FileAppender.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileAppender.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1.run(FileAppender.scala:38)
16/01/12 23:26:14 INFO Worker: Executor app-20160112232613-0012/0 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143
16/01/12 23:26:14 INFO Worker: Cleaning up local directories for application app-20160112232613-0012
```

I am newbie to Spark and its processing.Please help me out in this.

Comment: Did you check the access permissions for this `/spark/spark-1.4.1/work/app-20160112232613-0012/0/stderr` file? Anyway it might be not onlye issue here (why worker kills executor in first place?).

Comment: Are you working on AWS?

Comment: @DawidPura : Yes it has all rights and im executing as root user. Could it be like its not taking my jar for execution?

Comment: @Rami No. Im not workng on aws

Comment: You can check how logs look like from the Master site.

Comment: We are seeing the same exception on a worker running inside a docker container where everything is running as root and the ./work/ directory is world writable.

Answer (score 4):

The error is not caused by the java.io.IOException since you can see clearly `16/01/12 23:26:14 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20160112232613-0012/0`. This exception is raised afterwards when spark tries to write the log files, in which you will also observe the cause of your error.

Even if you run with `root` privilege spark-submit, it is the `spark` user that writes the files. I am guessing you are running on your laptop this. Try running `sudo chmod -R 777` on your spark folder.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was, spark driver was not able to get the dependencies from the executable jar that was submitted. Merged all dependencies and converted them to a single executable. It fixed the issue.

Please bear with my terminologies :)